# Why can't I parse this English date correctly in Java 8?

Tags: java, date

I want to execute a simple example to parse string to date with pattern.

```
String input = "Sep 31 2013";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy"));
```

It throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sep 31 2013' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source)
    at lambda.DateTime.main(DateTime.java:78)
```

I use java.time package from java 8.

Comment: Works for me. What is your default `Locale`?

Comment: `ru_RU` is my default locale

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a non-english `Locale`. If you want to parse in English, use the appropriate `Locale`

```
String input = "Sep 31 2013";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("MMM d yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Or any other English `Locale`: US, CANADA, UK, etc.

Alternatively, for your `Locale`, `ru_RU`, pass a Russian date String, ie. where `Sep` is in Russian so that it can be parsed appropriately