# Java java.time.format.DateTimeParseException on String

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a date to convert it to epochs. I tried the solution of a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970229/how-to-parse-date-correctly-in-java-8) without success:

```
String date = "Jun 4 2015";    
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("LLL dd yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime ldt  = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
System.out.println(date+" "+ldt.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

And I get `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jun 4 2015' could not be parsed at index 0` even though I am fairly certain that my regular expression [is correct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). What am I missing here?

EDIT:

Following the comments, I changed LocalDateTime to LocalDate, but keep getting the same error:

```
String date = "Jun 4 2015";    
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate ldt  = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518954/datetimeformatter-month-pattern-letter-l-fails

Comment: I replaced "LLL" with "MMM" and obtained the same result.

Comment: Using MMM is not sufficient. What you have there is a LocalDate, not a LocalDateTime: there is no time at all. Parse it to a LocalDate, then choose the time you want to transform it to a LocalDateTime.

Comment: I changed LocalDateTime to LocalDate and get the same issue...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    String date = "Jun 4 2015";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate ldt  = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

parses fine.  Don't put the "dd" as it won't parse days less than 10.  As @JB Nizet said, you'll need to use LocalDate, not LocalDateTime.